# Is this CSS duplicated and unnecessary?

Tags: html, css, gradient

Owing to the same RGBA value, i.e 0.0.0.0.5 repeated 4 times, surely this could be simplified?

```
#main > header {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../.jpg");
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../.jpg");
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../.jpg");
}
```

The purpose of this code is for gradient values but there is no gradient - it is being used as opacity hence my question...so surely there is an easier approach and just have one line of CSS rather than all these variations?

Thanks for all help

Comment: Yes: you can also create a pseudo element that covers the entire header element with a background colour of `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`. Also, there is really no need to prefix `linear-gradient` anymore: all evergreen browsers support the non-prefixed property today.

Comment: [Check the support of gradient](https://caniuse.com/css-gradients) Hint: Modern browsers don't need any of the prefixes.

Comment: They help to make some part of your code to work with all the browsers out there. Without them, you can make it work only on chrome or safari maybe but it wont work on mozilla or IE, so using these lines would allow all users to see whats going on, instead of just making it for some of them. PS: I meant about -webkit- , -moz- , -ms-.

Comment: @LeoRamadani they don't help anymore for gradient. Even for IE it's not needed

Comment: @LeoRamadani Typical case of prefix-itis. There is no need to prefixes for most browsers today. It's 2021. In fact, many `-ms-` prefixed properties don't even exist.

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh I thought they still do. Thanks for this info.